# how to remove an array object element at a particular time react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, time

i want to remove the array element if it's arrivalTime is equal to the current time
i tried
`time==traintime5? arrivalarr.pop(): []`
but it didn't worked,
i also tried array.filter but didn't worked
so please any one help me.
thankyou

full code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react';

function Home() {

  var today = new Date(),
  time = today.toLocaleTimeString(today.getHours, today.getMinutes);
 const date1 = today.toLocaleDateString(today.getDate);
var traintime1= today.toLocaleTimeString( today.setMinutes(31,0,0));
var traintime2= today.toLocaleTimeString( today.setMinutes(17,0,0));
var traintime3= today.toLocaleTimeString( today.setMinutes(19,0,0));
var traintime4= today.toLocaleTimeString( today.setMinutes(11,0,0));
var traintime5= today.toLocaleTimeString( today.setMinutes(18,0,0));

  
  
  const arrivalarr= [
    {
      TrainName : "train1",
      TrainNo : "1234",
      platformno : "1",
      arrivalTime : traintime1
    },
    {
      TrainName : "train2",
      TrainNo : "1235",
      platformno : "2",
      arrivalTime : traintime2
    },
    {
      TrainName : "train3",
      TrainNo : "1236",
      platformno : "3",
      arrivalTime : traintime3
    },
    {
      TrainName : "train4",
      TrainNo : "1237",
      platformno : "4",
      arrivalTime : traintime4
    },
    {
      TrainName : "train5",
      TrainNo : "1238",
      platformno : "5",
      arrivalTime : traintime5
    }
  ]
```

and this is my return , in this i wanted ony 4 trains when the time current time reaches any of the above 5 set time.

```
    <div>
       <div>
        <span> Arrival table </span><br />
       <span>Bangalore  Time  {time}   date  {date1}</span><br />
       train name     trainno   platformno   arrivalTime <br />
        {arrivalarr.map(({TrainName, TrainNo, platformno, arrivalTime})=>(
          
          <p key={TrainName}>  {TrainName}  {TrainNo} {platformno}    {arrivalTime}</p>
          
        ))}
      
        </div> 
    </div>
  )
 
  }


export default Home
```

Comment: What type of check do you want? If you desire to remove an element without a browser refresh, then you should set a timer to check if time has already passed or not. and check that for example every 10 seconds or every minute.

On the other hand, if you want to remove only after the browser refreshes, it is already another method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout to remove the train from the array, but you can't do calculations with a locale time string. You have no idea how that string will be formatted since it depends on the user's locale, and it doesn't even include the day.

Use an ISO string instead, then you can calculate the amount of time before removing the entry.

```
const currentTime = Date.now();
const arrivalTime1 = new Date(currentTime + 5000).toISOString();
const arrivalTime2 = new Date(currentTime + 10000).toISOString();
const arrivalTime3 = new Date(currentTime + 15000).toISOString();
const arrivalTime4 = new Date(currentTime + 20000).toISOString();
const arrivalTime5 = new Date(currentTime + 25000).toISOString();

const arrivalarr = [
  {
    TrainName: 'train1',
    TrainNo: '1234',
    platformno: '1',
    arrivalTime: arrivalTime1,
  },
  {
    TrainName: 'train2',
    TrainNo: '1235',
    platformno: '2',
    arrivalTime: arrivalTime2,
  },
  {
    TrainName: 'train3',
    TrainNo: '1236',
    platformno: '3',
    arrivalTime: arrivalTime3,
  },
  {
    TrainName: 'train4',
    TrainNo: '1237',
    platformno: '4',
    arrivalTime: arrivalTime4,
  },
  {
    TrainName: 'train5',
    TrainNo: '1238',
    platformno: '5',
    arrivalTime: arrivalTime5,
  },
];
```

```
  const [arrivals, setArrivals] = useState(arrivalarr);
  useEffect(() => {
    for (const arrival of arrivals) {
      const timeout = new Date(arrival.arrivalTime).getTime() - Date.now();
      setTimeout(
        () => setArrivals((prev) => prev.filter((a) => !Object.is(a, arrival))),
        timeout
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ihyvxp?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter()` method.

```
arrivalarr.filter((item) => {
  return item.arrivalTime !== time;  
});
```